# MERGE with ROW_NUMBER - Tbl1 as main table | tbl2 merging in | merge on latest entry in tbl1 only

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm wanting to merge two tables together (tbl1 and tbl2)

Tbl1 is the master table containing all products and the price change history.

Tbl2 contains only products that have had changes made that day

I want to compare tbl2 against tbl1, and when the latest entry for a product on tbl1 has a different price than the price listed on tbl2, it should create a new line entry on tbl1. If the data matches, no changes are required.

I understand Merge into and Row_Number but that seems to work on an instance where I'm merging tbl1 into tbl2, not the other way

for example

```
MERGE INTO tbl1 USING tbl2
ON CONCAT(tbl1.product, tbl1.price) = CONCAT(tbl2.product, tbl2.price)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (CHANGE_ID, product, price, UPDATED_AT, MODIFIED_DATETIME) 
            values (CONCAT(current_time, product), product, price, UPDATED_AT, MODIFIED_DATETIME);
```

This code will however search against all entries. What I was hoping to do was somehow use the ROW_NUMBER() like below, but it only seems possible to do ROW_NUMBER on the table your brining in to merge

```
MERGE INTO 
(select * FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY product ORDER BY MODIFIED_DATETIME DESC) AS ROWCOUNT, product, price FROM tbl1) where ROWCOUNT = 1) tblnew
USING tbl2
ON CONCAT(tblnew.product, tblnew.price) = CONCAT(tbl2.product, tbl2.price)
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT (CHANGE_ID, product, price, UPDATED_AT, MODIFIED_DATETIME) 
                values (CONCAT(current_time, product), product, price, UPDATED_AT, MODIFIED_DATETIME);
```

I have even tried creating a select clause first and setting that as the table then using that in the merge. I think this is more likely the correct way forward, I just can't seem to bring the table across for use in the merge

```
Select * from(select * FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY product ORDER BY MODIFIED_DATETIME DESC) AS ROWCOUNT, product, price FROM tbl1) where ROWCOUNT = 1) as tblnew
MERGE INTO tblnew USING tbl2
    ON CONCAT(tblnew.product, tblnew.price) = CONCAT(tbl2.product, tbl2.price)
        WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
            INSERT (CHANGE_ID, product, price, UPDATED_AT, MODIFIED_DATETIME) 
                    values (CONCAT(current_time, product), product, price, UPDATED_AT, MODIFIED_DATETIME);
```

Would I be better using an INSERT INTO? Part of the reason I wanted to use MERGE INTO is to increment the modified_datetime for any that match, so I can identify products that have not been checked.

Edited to add source example

#### Tbl1

| Change_ID | Product | Price | Updated_At | Modified_dateTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| apple02/05/2022 | apple | 1.30 | 02/05/2022 | 02/05/2022 11:11:01 |
| orange02/05/2022 | orange | 0.99 | 02/05/2022 | 02/05/2022 11:11:02 |
| pear02/05/2022 | pear | 1.50 | 02/05/2022 | 02/05/2022 11:11:03 |
| pear03/05/2022 | pear | 1.60 | 03/05/2022 | 03/05/2022 17:10:00 |
| apple03/05/2022 | apple | 1.40 | 03/05/2022 | 03/05/2022 17:10:01 |

#### Tbl2

| Product | Price | Updated_At |
| --- | --- | --- |
| apple | 1.30 | 04/05/2022 |
| orange | 0.99 | 04/05/2022 |
| pear | 1.60 | 04/05/2022 |

I would therefore expect apple to add a new row on with it's different than the last price held.

#### Tbl1 after merge

| Change_ID | Product | Price | Updated_At | Modified_dateTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| apple02/05/2022 | apple | 1.30 | 02/05/2022 | 02/05/2022 11:11:01 |
| orange02/05/2022 | orange | 0.99 | 02/05/2022 | 02/05/2022 11:11:02 |
| pear02/05/2022 | pear | 1.50 | 02/05/2022 | 02/05/2022 11:11:03 |
| pear03/05/2022 | pear | 1.60 | 03/05/2022 | 03/05/2022 17:10:00 |
| apple03/05/2022 | apple | 1.40 | 03/05/2022 | 03/05/2022 17:10:01 |
| apple04/05/2022 | apple | 1.30 | 04/05/2022 | 04/05/2022 16:00:00 |

Comment: Please also include sample source data and expected output.

Comment: I've edited and added an example of tbl1 and tbl2 and then what the expectation would be for tbl1 after the merge
thanks for any help you may be able to offer

Comment: I will try and re-check and solution and then post.

Comment: Thank you so much. 
Playing about I've realised by adding in PRICE to the select, it will of course always pick out the two previous apple prices and add the new one that doesn't match the previous. I have just amended the code to be `SELECT product, MAX(a.Updated_at) as Updated`  This seems to work now. Thank you. Though am looking into the new product being added

Comment: for new product you can just do UNION ALL select * from Tbl2 where product not in (select product from tbl1)) -- at the end

Comment: I've edited solution and checked for re-insert as well (it does not re-inserts). Also included for additional entries in tbl2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following query will give latest entry from tbl1 as per updated_dt

```
select * from tbl1 qualify row_number() 
over (partition by product order by updated_at desc)=1
```

Combine above query with data from tbl2 to get data as per condition " when the latest entry for a product on tbl1 has a different price than the price listed on tbl2"  -

```
select distinct a.* from
tbl2 a,
(select * from tbl1 qualify row_number() 
over (partition by product order by updated_at desc)=1) b
where a.product = b.product
and a.price != b.price -- different price
```

To include additional rows in tbl2 that are missing from tbl1 UNION can be used as -

```
select distinct a.* from
tbl2 a,
(select * from tbl1 qualify row_number() 
over (partition by product order by updated_at desc)=1) b
where a.product = b.product
and a.price != b.price
UNION ALL -- Add any rows in tbl2 that are new and not present in tbl1
select * from Tbl2 where product not in (select product from tbl1);
```

Using above select INSERT can be performed as -

```
insert into tbl1 
select 
product||to_char(Updated_At,'dd/mm/yyyy'),product,price,updated_at,current_timestamp()
from
(
select distinct a.* from
tbl2 a,
(select * from tbl1 qualify row_number() 
over (partition by product order by updated_at desc)=1) b
where a.product = b.product
and a.price != b.price
UNION ALL
select * from Tbl2 where product not in (select product from tbl1)
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your time on this.

I think for myself I would be wanting max Updated_At and not Price, so have amended that line the code slightly

`code
(select distinct b.*
from tbl1 a ,tbl2 b, (select product, price, max(a.price) as Updated_At from tbl1 a group by product, price) c`

The only other thing for me is that if a new product, say plum was introduced, this wouldn't pick that up. I'm assuming I would have to add in an IF statement? Can you think of any better way?

Comment: that was meant to be max(a.Updated_at)

Although testing this I'm running into issue where upon re-running the code on the same tbl2 data, tbl1 updates, adds on the same apple row again....

Comment: I have added to include additional values in tbl2. For max price or date, I believe adjustments can be made by you as needed.

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help with this.
Your original code was great and just needed a little tweak to meet my criteria, with some errors by myself along the way.

Still learning myself, and this was very helpful.